# How to access Json data in this case?

Tags: json

I have a tree table that contains many check boxes. Each check box it stores the structure itself. For example `/root/entity_child/0/entity_child/1`. From this data, I would like to use it and read the Json object from my Json data.

To get the right data, I need something like mydata.root.entity_child[0].entity_child[1]. But I don't know how should I apply my raw data which is string to get the data that I want.

Let say, I have string of `/root/entity_child/0/entity_child/1`, how can I transform this to `mydata.root.entity_child[0].entity_child[1] in javascript?`

Any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue what your question is. What language are we talking about even?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I just javascript

Comment: But what is your actual **problem**? What code have you written? What does it do, and what doesn't it do? What output are you expecting?

Comment: my problem is I have string which is something like /root/entity_child/0/entity_child/1. How can I transform this to access the structure of json data in programming way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it's not clear if you need to get:

- The value of `mydata.root.entity_child[0].entity_child[1]`,
- Or just the string `"mydata.root.entity_child[0].entity_child[1]"`

If you want the value, then you can split the string by `"/"` and loop through:

```
function getValue(path, from){
    var splitStr = path.substr(1).split('/');
    var val = from;

    for(var i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i ++){
        val = val[splitStr[i]];
    }

    return val;
}

getValue('/root/entity_child/0/entity_child/1', mydata);
```

Or if you only want the string, then you can do all in one line using regex:

```
'mydata' + '/root/entity_child/0/entity_child/1'.replace(/\/([0-9]+)/g, "[$1]").replace(/\//g, '.');
```